# Xcode simulator builds only in one size // for one device

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator, xcode6.4

... no matter which device I choose to simulate on. The problem has occured after last update (last week). Every device gives me the same simulator's window /I think I'd be iPhone6Plus/.

I will be grateful for any hints how to be able to simulate on different devices again.

My sys ver: Version 10.10 (915) Xcode: Version: 6.4

Regards, W.wa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried cleaning the derived data and restarting XCode?
You can also try a full project cleaning (holding down option key and select clean build) and reset the simulator (iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have tried them all out, none worked for me. I also reinstalled Xcode, again nothing.